# Extending class, implicit super constructor is undefined error

Tags: java, processing

I am using Java. I have got 2 classes

```
class Card
class Deck extends Card
```

I get a constructor error.

I have to make a blackjack game for college and Deck class has to be extended.

What can I do to solve this problem?

```
class Card
{
    int rank, suit;
    String[] suits = { "hearts", "spades", "diamonds", "clubs" };
    String[] ranks  = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

    Card(int suit, int rank)
    {
        this.rank=rank;
        this.suit=suit;
    }

    String toString()
    {
          return ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit];
    }

    int getRank() {
         return rank;
    }

    int getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }
}




class Deck extends Card{

    ArrayList <Card> cards;
    int numberdeck;
    Deck()
    {
        cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
        for (int a=0; a<=3; a++)
        {
            for (int b=0; b<=12; b++)
            {
                cards.add( new Card(a,b) );
            }
        }
    }

    Card drawFromDeck()
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        int index= generator.nextInt( cards.size() );
        return cards.remove(index);
    }

    int getTotalCards()
    {
        return cards.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor in the subclass is supposed to invoke the corresponding constructor in the super class, but, such a constructor is not found in your code.

Either add a constructor that takes no argument to the superclass or make the constructor in the subclass invoke the constructor in the superclass.

You can invoke the constructor of the superclass using `super(0, 0);` at the beginning of the body of the constructor of the subclass.

Comment: What would be the difference in each way?

Answer (score 2):

`Deck` really ought not extend `Card`. Sub-classing encodes an *is-a* relationship. A lion is an animal, so `Lion extends Animal`. You can tell that sub-classing is inappropriate because the getRank() and getSuit() methods make no sense on an entire deck of cards.

A deck of cards is not a card; a deck *contains* other cards. The *contains* relationship is already represented by the `ArrayList <Card> cards` array.

Comment: that is what we have to do. we have got 2 options. Option 1= class Deck implements CardInterface or Option2: class Deck extends Card

Comment: @baris22 Well, no offense to your professor, but both options are bad object-oriented design.

Comment: In doubt ever choose the Interface approach, at least for your next home assignment. Inheritance was a technic popular 15 years ago. there are many disadvantages in inheritance.

Comment: It's possible the professor is showing old methods and moving into showing new methods so that the programming students have a broad knowledge set and can make more informed decisions.